# C# out Parameter with null check

Tags: c#

I would like to make use of `out` or `ref` parameters that may not be assigned prior to calling the function. The function then is responsible for checking whether the parameter exists, and if not, creates and returns a new object.

Here is some example C# code for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public virtual object MyFunction(out object myObject)
{
    if (myObject == null)
        myObject = new Object();

    // do some more things here...
    // maybe return myObject, or perhaps something else
    return myObject;
}
```

I would like each of the four example function calls below to be considered valid:

```
Object x = new Object();
MyFunction(x);               // x gets passed by reference
Object y = MyFunction(x);
Object z = MyFunction();
Object u = MyFunction(null);
```

I get an error on line 3 telling me that `Out parameter 'list' might not be initialized before accessing`. Attempting to give `myObject` a default value gives the error `A 'ref' or 'out' parameter cannot have a default value`.

Is there a way to use `out` parameters (pass by reference) and check to see if those references have been initialized *before* assigning them to anything?

Comment: Most likely not. Use `ref` instead.

Comment: I think the compiler already answered this question for you. That said, `MyFunction()` has no reason to be using an `out` parameter. It returns the result.

Comment: Also, none of the four function calls that you wish were valid is *passing* an `out` parameter. If a parameter is `out object myObject`, the compiler expects `f(out o)`, and it's not going to meet you halfway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  If you use an `out` parameter then you are not permitted to read the value before assigning to the variable, for the reason the compiler has already told you.  If you use `ref` then the parameter *must* be initialized before it is allowed to be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Return values are most of the time the right choice when the method doesn't have anything else to return.

It only stops the caller from having to declare the variable separately. Example:

```
int x1;
GetValue(out x1);
```

Declaring a variable:

```
int? x1 = GetValue();
```

You can read more about it in thi [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a null as your out parameter, e.g. by using `out _`, the CLR will allocate temporary storage when you first use the parameter so there is no need for the initial check that won't compile.

[image: Before assignment]

Step over this line (there is no exception):

[image: After assignment]

The call was `double result = TestMethods.DoubleValue(2.5, out _);`